# W/Parcel ( 4230): Expecting binder but got null! Error

Tags: flutter, dart

There is no error in my application, but I get the error I wrote in the title.

The error that pops up:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62778/IYmUUuhGaGs=/ws
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...
I/utter_movie_app( 4230): Compiler allocated 4533KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
W/Parcel  ( 4230): Expecting binder but got null!
```

The code in my main.dart file:

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  unawaited(
      SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]));
  unawaited(getIt.init());

  runApp(const MovieApp());
}

class MovieApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MovieApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenUtil.init();

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Movie App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: AppColor.blackBackgroundColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColor.blackBackgroundColor,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        textTheme: ThemeText.getTextTheme(),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(elevation: 0),
      ),
      home: const HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Someone else has also shared the error I received. I tried the solutions written there, but the error I got did not go away in any way. I asked artificial intelligence and tried the solutions there, but the problem still did not go away.